# Calculating week number SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query where I need to calculate the week number based on the fiscal start of the year occurring on 01.07.YEAR

The problem I have is that when it goes to 30 Days of a calendar year I don't get the correct result and so I need to amend my script.  I want a query that returns the correct week number regardless of what month I am in.

I have a calendar table populated; I add 18 months to the current date which give me the period and so I tried to do the same to the week but I am going around in circles.

Below is the code I am using:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
SELECT
  [date],
  DATEPART(wk, DATEADD(MONTH, 18, DATEADD(dd, -2, [date]))) 'FWeek',
  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 18, [date]), 112), 6) AS 'Period',
  DATENAME(dw, [date]) AS 'Day'
FROM [dbo].[DP_PERIOD_DATES]
WHERE [date] >= '01/11/2018'
AND [date] < '04-01-2019'
ORDER BY [date] DESC
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and a desired output

Answer (score 0):

Try datediff to get the number of weeks from 1/7/x.
The extra datediff is to get the first of the year and add 6 to get the 7th of the year.

```
SELECT [date],
DateDiff(wk, 
--JANUARY 7th of Current Year
DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, DATEADD(m,18,[date])), 0)+6
, DATEADD(m,18,[date]))
FROM [dbo].[DP_PERIOD_DATES]
WHERE [date] >= '01/11/2018'
AND [date] < '04-01-2019'
ORDER BY [date] DESC
```

Comment: thanks for your answer; the issue I have is that I have to add 18 months to the date in question and then display the weeknumber + year for that date

Comment: i modified the query to add 18 months to the date before figuring out the weeknumber.  if this is not what you are looking for, send an example of a date and the expected result.

Comment: Hey; this doesnt work either:   the one in the middle is what I am trying to get; the fiscal year started on the 01.07 and so I am adding 18 months to the date but trying to return the weekNo of this

Comment: 2019-01-01  202027 25

Comment: If you add 18 months to 1/1/2019, you get 7/1/2020 which is 25 weeks from 1/7/2020 which is what is showing in the query.  What should it do with 1/1/2019?

Comment: Hi Paul, the 31.12 and 01.01 is week 27, so I am trying to get this.  I am trying to apply teh same logic to a table that was there before hence why I am so confussed

Comment: the 30 - 24 is week 26

Comment: when I get to the 26.11 is when it gives me an issue as it returns: 26/11/2018 202022 21 week 21 but it should be week 22

Comment: SET DATEFIRST 1;
select  [date], Fweek
, DATEPART(wk, DATEADD(month, 18, Dateadd(dd,-2,[date]))) 'FWeek Maureen'
 ,LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, 18, [date]),112),6) as 'Period'
 , datename(dw,[date])  as Day
from [dbo].[DP_PERIOD_DATES] 
WHERE  [date] >= '01/11/2018'
and [date]< '04-01-2019'
order by [date] DESC

Comment: if you look at 26-11-2018 it shows Week = 21 but this should be Week = 22 as it only returns 6 days in this week, so I am very confused

Comment: If you describe your exact calculation in words, I can give you the sql.  For example:  For any date, add 18 months (so that Feb 13,2018 becomes July 13,2019), then count how many Tuesdays come before it in the calendar year.  Or, add 18 months, then count how many days there are from Jan 7th of that year and divide by 7 and drop the divisor.

There are many definitions of week number.  So if I know how you would calculate manually, it will be easy to automate.

Comment: Hi Paul,Thanks for your help.  The first day of the Fiscal calendar is 01.07 Year; so I guess this is the starting point of the week numbers.  I had tried to input a case statment which read if the month fell with 30 days but again this does not work for me.

Comment: --SET DATEFIRST 1;
select  [date], Fweek
,case when datename(MONTH,[date]) IN ('APRIL', 'JUNE', 'SEPTEMBER', 'NOVEMBER') then
 DATEPART(wk, DATEADD(month, 18, Dateadd(dd,-1,[date]))) 
 when datename(MONTH,[date]) IN ('FEBRUARY') then
 DATEPART(wk, DATEADD(month, 18, Dateadd(dd,0,[date]))) 
ELSE
 DATEPART(wk, DATEADD(month, 18, Dateadd(dd,0,[date]))) 
end 'FWeek Maureen'
 ,LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, 18, [date]),112),6) as 'Period'
from [dbo].[DP_PERIOD_DATES] 
WHERE  [date] >= '01/01/2018' and [date]< '04-01-2019' order by [date] asc

Answer (score 0):

SET FWEEK =  DATENAME(yy, (DATEADD(month, 18, [date]))) + RIGHT('00'+DATENAME(dy,(datepart(DAYOFYEAR,DATEDIFF(DY,0,[date])/7*7+547)+5)/7),2) 
, period =  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, 18, [date]),112),6)

Thanks Paul for all your help; it really wasnt easy as trying to apply someone elses logic to a date.  I got it working using the above code in case anyone is looking for the same type of answer in the future